# Как сделать тексты которые были оставлены в textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

Написал код:

```
<textarea cols="100" placeholder="Напишите ваше сообщение."></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Как сделать так что бы все сообщение которые были оставлены в textarea отображались ниже?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
const messages = document.getElementById("messages");

form.onsubmit = function () {
  if (textarea.value) {
    const message = document.createElement("p");
    message.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    messages.appendChild(message);
    textarea.value = "";
    textarea.focus()
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
<div id="messages"></div>
```